# Search using REGEXP with no repeating characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, database

I have a databse of english words and i want to use regexp to search in this database
i used this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `english` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(words)=4  AND  `words` REGEXP '^[oofd]+$'
```

it is working and its selecting the words like `food,foo,of,do`
but it is also selecting the words like `fooo` with 3 o's but in my regexp there is just 2 o's
what is the right regular expression to select words with no repeating characters 
if there is two character **for example** `oo`   it will select just words with two `o` or **1** or **zero** ,**not three or more**

I looked in the internet i came with this:

```
^(?:([oofd])(?!.*\1))
```

but it gives me an error:

> #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: MySQL regex does not support non-capturing groups, nor lookaheads, nor backreferences. Anyway, that is a wrong regex for this task. And regex is not the right tool here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so what is the alternative for doing this ?

Comment: Can you us a decent example of what should match and what should not match?

Comment: `[...]` is a range. It matches one of the characters it contains. Putting duplicate characters inside the range definition doesn't have any effect. `[oofd]` is the same as `[ofd]`. The order also doesn't matter. It is the same as `[dfo]`, `[dof]` etc.

Comment: @axiac i know it is same but how to search for a words with just 1 o or less is there a way to limit characters?

Comment: "Bookkeeping" is my favorite word for double letters.

Comment: Would "banana" be considered to have 3 a's?  Your question does not explicitly say they need to be adjacent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the *presence* of two vowels in sequence and the *absence* of three or more vowels in sequence:

```
SELECT *
FROM english
WHERE
    words REGEXP '^.*[aeiou]{2}.*$' AND
    words NOT REGEXP '^.*[aeiou]{3}.*$'
```

If you only want to look for certain repeated vowels, you should be able to adapt this answer fairly easily.

Comment: Hell Yeah, I totally got some Thread-Head! Thanks! @Tim-Biegeleisen